# Using global variables Cpp

Tags: c++, global-variables

I am newbie in C++. Previously, I learnt the C language and decide to shift to learn C++ language. However, I find something hard for me to follow, particularly in using global variables. I wrote a program and I get wrong. When I tried to debug, my program show error in the line

```
item* list = ::array[index].head;
```

in which `item` is

```
class item
{
public: 
    int key, data;
    item* next;
};
```

and `array` is a global variable which is define as

```
class arrayitem
{
public:
    item* head;
    item* tail;
};
arrayitem* array;
```

Edit: This is what I get when I debug my program:
[image]

Comment: My advice, remove all mutable globals.  Constants are fine, but when you start mutating global state it makes it very hard to reason about the code and can be the source of painful bugs.

Comment: @NathanOliver however, I need to use global variables to reduce the parameters passed into the function.

Comment: That's doubtful.  If you have lots of parameters you encapsulate them into a object.  You can also use member functions so that you don't need to pass the object to the function, but just call the function on the object.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's a good advice. However, as I've mentioned, I'm new in Cpp and OOP (Object-oriented programming). So, you can see that I wrote my program nearly same as C program. First I need to solve this problem to understand the global variables in Cpp

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].  How do you initialize `array` etc.?

Comment: Why does being new stop you from doing it "the right way"?  If you start off with good habits, you wont have bad ones to break later.  It takes a lot more time to unlearn habits then it does to learn the right one the first time.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know it's good. But my function is ``void`` so I still don't know how to use it in a ``class``. Or I need to change it to another form of function?

Comment: Do you happen to have `using namespace std;` in your code? `std::list` exists, and if you try to name variable `list` when `using namespace std;` is in place then error happens. Other than that, I don't see any possible issues with the line you've shown. We would need [mcve] to help you - include full error message you got.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Of course I did add ``using namespace std;`` and I get this error

Comment: @HoangNam Please see ["Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: I have updated my question with a photo of debug error. All of you can check it for me to give me some advice to fix it

Comment: How do you initialize `array`? The issue is either that `index` is out of bounds for `array` or `array` was not initialized at all.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I initialize ``array`` by `` arrayitem *array = nullptr;``. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @HoangNam You are dereferencing `array` in `::array[index]`. You cannot dereference a null pointer. That is the same rule as in C.

Comment: You say you know some C, what would happen if you did `int* a = NULL; printf("%d", a[0]);`?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I think that it change the value to 0 and has the address into the address of NULL

Comment: @HoangNam Note that in the image shown `array` is clearly *not* null so you must have set it elsewhere.  That's why you need to provide a [mcve].